# Populating array from file

Tags: arrays, bash, populate

I've searched google and nowhere found the answer. I'm getting a function to populate an array from file:

```
#!/bin/bash

PusherListV2=()
PusherListV3=()

getArray () {
        if ! [ -f $2 ]; then return 2
        fi
        i=0
        while read p; do
                PusherList$1[$i]="$p"
                ((i++))
        done <$2
}

getArray V2 /tmp/test.txt

echo ${PusherListV2[@]}
```

I'm getting this kind of error to this:

```
./test.sh: line 11: PusherListV2[0]=p01: command not found
./test.sh: line 11: PusherListV2[1]=p02: command not found
./test.sh: line 11: PusherListV2[2]=p03: command not found
./test.sh: line 11: PusherListV2[3]=p04: command not found
./test.sh: line 11: PusherListV2[4]=p05: command not found
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Remove double quotes from `PusherList$1[$i]="$p"`! It should be simply `PusherList$1[$i]=$p`.

Comment: What about `PusherListV2=($(cat test.txt))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variable substitution in assignment to construct the variable name. This doesn't work:

```
PusherList$1[$i]="$p"
```

Replace with:

```
eval PusherList$1[$i]=\"\$p\"
```

or even just this (as shekhar suman says, quotes are not particularly useful here):

```
eval PusherList$1[$i]=\$p
```

As long as you control `$1` and `$i`, this should be a safe use of `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple solution using `readarray`. Here is the test file:

```
$ cat file.tmp
first line
second line
third line
```

Now I read the file and store the lines in an array:

```
$ readarray mytab < file.tmp
```

Finally I check the array:

```
$ declare -p mytab
declare -a mytab='([0]="first line
" [1]="second line
" [2]="third line
")'
```

As you can see the lines are stored with the `\n`. Remove them with `-t`.

Now to solve your problem you can pass the array by reference in the function with the new nameref attribute (bash 4.3+), no need of `eval`:

```
PusherListV2=()
PusherListV3=()

getArray () array file
{
    local -n array="$1"    # nameref attribute
    local file="$2"

    test -f "$file" || return 2

    readarray -t array < "$file"
}

getArray PusherListV2 /tmp/test.txt

echo "${PusherListV2[@]}"    # always "" arround when using @
```

If you still want to pass `V2` instead of `PusherListV2` you simply have to write

```
    local -n array="PusherList$1"    # nameref attribute
```

in the function.

Comment: namerefs are not necessary at all!

Comment: yes they are if you want to avoid global variables.

Comment: `readarray -t "$1" < "$file"` would avoid the nameref altogether.

Comment: In fact, but if then you want to do something on the array in the function, you can using nameref and locals.

Comment: I would like to use a global variable to use it in other functions... This is why I'm not using local variables. And I'm using debian server - bash 4.2.37

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a function that takes two arguments:

- First argument is a string that will be appended to `PusherList` to obtain an array name
- Second argument is a file name

The function should put each line of the file in the array.

Easy, in Bash≥4:

```
getArray() {
    [[ -f $2 ]] || return 2
    # TODO: should also check file is readable
    mapfile -t "PusherList$1" < "$2"
    # TODO: check that mapfile succeeded
    # (it may fail if e.g., PusherList$1 is not a valid variable name)
}
```

The `-t` option to `mapfile` so that the trailing newlines are trimmed.

**Note.** This is very likely going to be the most efficient method.

Comment: @EdouardThiel yeah, and the name `mapfile` is usually preferred.